# How to show pretty json text when even it's not json form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a textarea that already show some json string. And I can edit directly on it. But when I trigger onChange and update value of textarea it's not json form anymore and I got the error. So I don't know how I can do properly.

More explain:
textarea showing

```
{
"Id":1,
"Action":"CONCAT",
"Targets":["eval(\"","link=\\\"","$Link","\\\";sp=link.split(\\\"__requestHeader=\\\");sp[0]\")"],
"Result":"$str_Link"
}
```

And I try to delete "Result" out of it but When I delete Quotation mark make Its not Json anymore, show I can't delete anymore.

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mendeleev-6641iw?file=/src/App.js:0-1079

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([
    {
      Id: 1,
      Action: "CONCAT",
      Targets: [
        'eval("',
        'link=\\"',
        "$Link",
        '\\";sp=link.split(\\"__requestHeader=\\");sp[0]")'
      ],
      Result: "$str_Link"
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Action: "CONCAT",
      Targets: [
        'eval("',
        'link=\\"',
        "$Link",
        '\\";sp=link.split(\\"__requestHeader=\\");sp[1]")'
      ],
      Result: "$str_Header"
    }
  ]);

  const valueHandleChange = (e, index) => {
    let newValue = [...value];
    newValue[index] = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <textarea
            spellCheck={false}
            onChange={(e) => valueHandleChange(e, index)}
            value={JSON.stringify(item, null, "\t")}
          ></textarea>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to remove the last `,` as well, otherwise it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below. I think we can ignore the react warning(not an error) as this is a special case.

```
const valueHandleChange = (e, index) => {
  try {
    let newValue = [...value];
    newValue[index] = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
    setValue(newValue);
  } catch (err) {
     //any operation can be performed here 
    console.log(err);
  }
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    {value.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <textarea
          spellCheck={false}
          onChange={(e) => valueHandleChange(e, index)}
          rows="20"
          cols="50"
          key={index}
        >
          {JSON.stringify(item, null, "\t")}
        </textarea>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-6u05e7?file=/src/Validation/JsonValidation/JsonValidation.js